# Recommended language for making monitoring service that makes HTTP requests

Tags: http, programming-languages

I want to build a program that will make HTTP requests to a web service of some sort, so it could monitor it's status and alert when it returns some responses.
My question is what language should I write it (I'm willing to learn new languages for this application) so it would be simple to write yet fast and effective.
.net framework is out of question since this process will run on Linux machines

Comment: FYI: Asking for language recommendations is considered off topic for this site.  This question may end up getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be set with Python: Its very own [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) is more than capable for the job. Regarding the notifications, I think [gntp](http://pythonhosted.org/gntp/) is right for you (unless you want to call `notify-send` yourself through [`os.exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl)).